# how call a function and arguments with inline asm (win32)

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, abi

I'm trying to call a function that takes an int and returns an int, but when I push the argument to the stack the program crashes:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    struct prot{
        void* retn;
        void* arg1;
        void* arg2;
        void* arg3;
        void* arg4;
        int arg_len;
    };

    typedef struct prot Prot;

    void c_func(void* fun,Prot* p){
           __asm__(
               "mov %2, %%eax\n\t"
               "push %%eax\n\t"
               "mov %1, %%eax\n\t" 
               "call *%%eax\n\t"      
               "mov %%eax, %0\n\t"
               "pop %%eax\n\t"
               : "=r"(p->retn)
               : "r" (fun), "r"(p->arg1)
               :"%eax"
           );

       //int r = (int)p->retn; 
    }

    typedef int(__stdcall *fp)(int);

    int main(){
            HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary("a1.dll");
        fp lpFunc = (fp)GetProcAddress(hDll, "i32");
            Prot p;
            p.arg1 = (void*)35;
            p.arg_len = 1;
            c_func(lpFunc,&p);
            printf("retorno: %d\n",(int)p.retn);
        FreeLibrary(hDll);
        return 0;
    }
```

Works now!
function i32 in a1.dll : __declspec( dllexport ) int i32(int y){
need be in asm for a custom ffi inteface

pass argument to function pointer

Comment: why `sub $4, %%esp`? Did you mean to add 4? There will also be problems with all the registers the function you call clobbers. I wouldn't use extended inline assembly for this. You could mark the function `c_func` with the `naked` attribute and then use basic inline assembly or just put this code in a separate assembly (asm) file.

Comment: Suggest you write your function in C, upload to Godbolt like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/v8PTjbYj8) and look at the assembly language it generates -- then compare with the in line asm you have here

Comment: You might offer a use case for this.  It looks inefficient compared to simply calling the function, or even using a function pointer in C.

Comment: I intend to create a ffi library , calling any function any argument

Comment: @Kz2023: That would only be fully accurate for a `naked` function.  In GNU C inline asm inside a normal function, the stack pointer might or might not already be aligned by 16.  (Oh, but I think that's ok on Win32 where the calling convention only requires it aligned by 4).  Also, it won't show you the clobber declarations you need, e.g. `"ecx", "edx", "st", "st1", ..., "xmm0","xmm1",...`.  And with an `"=a"(p->retn)` output constraint to tell the compiler it's in EAX (which is why we can omit it from clobbers.)

Comment: Removed sub 4 , esp and add eax to clobbers and add pop eax in end. Works now!

Comment: `__stdcall` is a callee-pops convention.  If you unconditionally push 4 args, different callees are still only going to pop as many as they actually wanted before returning.  I guess you *could* use that `int arg_len` member to figure out how many bytes to adjust ESP by, as long as the users of this function always know the right number of args for the function they're calling.  (Actually *size* of args; `long long` takes two slots.)  Or if you have different blocks of code for each size of args, that gets easier, perhaps taking an array of `uint32_t` of args to be pushed...

Comment: @Peter Cordes  -- all good points, thx, and I see it now too.  Guess I was just enamored of it as a new toy.  I'm going to cease recommending it as of now.

Comment: @Kz2023: https://godbolt.org/ is an amazing tool that's great for learning stuff about asm, like how calling conventions work.  The problem is: that's necessary but not *sufficient* to make calls from GNU C inline asm.  You have to accurately describe your asm to the compiler using constraints.

Comment: In general, Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk “[What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)” and [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) are great to link to asm beginners, and for seeing how your inline asm actually compiles as part of a function.  (But again, compiling to correct asm for one caller isn't sufficient to prove correctness; if you forget to declare some clobbers, it could break other callers that do care about that register.)